# Android: disable ListView selection

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView that I re-display with the correct answer highlighted when the user selects an item. However, at that point I would like to disable selection of list view items; the user can only get to the next question by pressing a button. However, even if I disable the items like so:

```
   private void disableItemSelection() {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++){
            View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
            v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

...it still highlights the selection when the user selects it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did u find a solution to this?

Comment: No - I did a workaround which takes them to the next question if they try to select a button again.

Answer (score 32):

The reason the scrolling is locked is because you are setting up at

```
ListView
```

I found a way to disable highlighting without locking the scroll. You need to set it up at ListAdapter as shown below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, strText) {
           public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
            { 
                    return false; 
            } 
        };
```

Comment: You don't need to use an ArrayAdapter, if you don't want to. Just override the isEnabled method on your own custom adapter and you're good to go!

Comment: doesn't it mean that if there is a drawable for the rows that has the disabled state , it will also change their image ? is it possible to disable clicking and yet not change the drawable ?

Answer (score 29):

You can add attribute to Listview XML layout to disable multiple high light rows as

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"               
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: I think this is the best ansewr, is always best to set this details in the xml than in the code.

Comment: For me it was enough just to set `listSelector`.

Answer (score 4):

I just hid the selected item with this:

```
listView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

And then you show it again by restoring to whatever drawable it was using previously:

```
wifiSsid.setSelector(R.drawable.listview_selector);
```

Answer (score 2):

I used android:`choiceMode="none"` as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3achoiceMode).

Comment: This only sets if list items can have a selected mode, but not the highlighting :(