# Android ListView Remove Selection

Tags: android, android-listview

Is there a way to elegantly remove the selection on a ListView. It would act in the opposite manner of ListView#setSelection(int position). I would like to programmatically remove the selection from the ListView (such that no item is selected). It does not appear the API has an easy way to do it. Any thoughts?

My question is similar to: [Android: disable ListView selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237120/android-disable-listview-selection)

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers worked for me so I did this:

```
    SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(positions.keyAt(i), false);
    }
```

Not very elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what i could do for this set the selection color and background both of the same color if possible 
or set selection with full alpha value that makes it transparent and even if selection is there it wont be visible anymore

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way I could find is to refresh the adapter the ListView is using:

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

ListView will then refresh, having the same choices but the selection highlight will be cleared.

Comment: This method does not exists (in my api v.19)

Comment: @Asterius, It's a method of the list adapter, not the ListView itself.

Comment: I would also like to comment that this is a method of the `BaseAdapter` concrete class, not the `ListAdapter` interface. A cast may be required if the type of the variable `listAdapter` is `ListAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `listView.setItemChecked(-1, true);`

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to clear a ListView selection:
`listView.SelectedItem = null;`