# how to deactiviate pressed style of a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a custom listview, but when i press an item I do not the default style of pressed applied to the particular row item.

**style before press (default)**:
[image]

**style after press (pressed) :**
[image]

code of my custom listview:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
String items[] = {"cat", "dog", "horse"};

list.setAdapter(new myAdapter(items));
```

now how can I remove these orange regions?

Comment: Do you completely want to deactivate the highlight or just get rid of those edges at the corners?

Comment: @PirateCube. completely deactivation

Comment: Please refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237120/android-disable-listview-selection

Comment: You welcome mate! Greetings from Kashmir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the following to my listview and my problem solved:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a drawable that has a transparent color in it, something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />
```

And then set by `code` :

```
listView.setSelector(R.drawable.my_transparent_selector);
```

and the `XML attribute` is:

```
android:listSelector
```