# Make dates of com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView unselectable

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, implementation

I have implemented `CalendarPickerView` from library https://github.com/square/android-times-square

```
<com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

in java Code

```
 calendar.init((Date) dates.get(0), d)
                        .inMode(com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
                        .withSelectedDates(dates);
```

dates is `ArrayList<Date> dates;` having continues dates.

I want that user should not able to click any date in calendar.
He will only see the highlighted date which is done only by us.

Comment: CalendarPickerView extends from ListView and here are some solutions for what you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237120/android-disable-listview-selection